# Disabling hibernation in debian testing (lxde)

Tags: debian, laptop, lxde, hibernate

I have a dell inspiron 6000 laptop running debian testing lxde. I can't figure out how to disable hibernation once the lid is closed. Do I modify the systmd files or the `lib/systemd/systemd-sleep <hybrid-sleep/hibernate>` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It is to edit the  conf. file in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` as described in [How to disable auto suspend when I close laptop lid?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52643/how-to-disable-auto-suspend-when-i-close-laptop-lid)