# How to disable suspend on close laptop lid on NixOS?

Tags: suspend, laptop, acpi, nixos

I'm using [NixOS](http://nixos.org) on a laptop and want to disable auto-suspension that happens every time I close the laptop lid. Approach described in “[How to disable auto suspend when I close laptop lid?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52643/11397)”, that is, editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` won't work, as it is just a symlink to `/etc/static/systemd/logind.conf`, which itself is a symlink to a file in `/nix/store`.

AFAIK, you shouldn't edit the *Nix store* directly, although I'm not entirely sure what would happen if I did. But the file in `/nix/store` doesn't have write permissions anyway.

How do I disable auto-suspension of a laptop in a NixOS idiomatic way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a configuration option [**services.logind.extraConfig**](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-services.logind.extraConfig).

Open your NixOS configuration file (`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`). Assign a string `"HandleLidSwitch=ignore"` (or whatever you would usually put into `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`) to that option:

```
services.logind.extraConfig = "HandleLidSwitch=ignore";
```

Answer (score 16):

While the solution proposed by Mirzhan will probably work, there is a much more elegant way using the [`services.logind.lidSwitch`](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-services.logind.lidSwitch) and [`services.logind.lidSwitchDocked`](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-services.logind.lidSwitchDocked) options.

Now, you can just write

```
services.logind.lidSwitch = "ignore";
```

These options also have types provided so an invalid configuration would be detected at build time.