# Laptop lid closing freeze - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, freeze

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a Dell inspiron 7559. I had a lot of trouble with the installation of almost any distro but this time it seemed that everything worked just fine. The first couple of times that I closed the lid and re-opened it, everything seemed to work fine, but now it doesn't. Namely, after it resumes, opening apps by clicking them is not a posibility any more. Do you have any ideas of how I can fix this bug?
Note that the laptop bares a NVIDIA card and I have installed the proprietary drivers.

`lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 79)
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Note that sometimes it freezes, sometimes it does not...which I find it even more weird..

Comment: The developers should fix the bug, not you. (unless you're an ubuntu developer). The most useful thing you can do is filling a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html).

Comment: Yeah, but it might be something that justs needs a fine tuning and not an actual bug.....

Comment: Something's needed a fine tuning is also a bug. Developers should do the fine tunings - this is the meaning and the goal of a distribution.

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci` Let's make sure this isn't a hybrid laptop before we file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Consider How to disabling auto suspend when you close the laptop lid:
[How to disable auto suspend when I close laptop lid?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52643/how-to-disable-auto-suspend-when-i-close-laptop-lid)

Comment: This seems to be a workaround rather than a solution.